# Trying to learn how bitwise or operator | works for python, and I'm wondering why 1 | 2 == 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried printing various integers (ie.  int | int ) multiple times and I can't seem to establish a working pattern of values. How does 1|2 return 3, but 2|3 also returns 3?

Comment: Bitwise operations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: Bitwise-OR means OR bitwise.

Answer (score 2):

Bitwise operators in Python work in the same way as in other languages. So, if you know how it works in C then you know how it works in Python. For this particular example, `1` is represented by binary `0001` and `2` by `0010`. Operator OR (`|`) looks at each bit in the two numbers *at the same position* and compares them. If *any* bit is 1 then it keeps 1 at *that* position in the result:

```
1: |  2:  result:
----------------
0  or 0   = 0
0  or 0   = 0
0  or 1   = 1
1  or 0   = 1
```

So the result (in binary format) is `0011` or, in base 10, `0011->3`.

Answer (score 1):

Check [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR).

> A bitwise OR takes two bit patterns of equal length and performs the
>   logical inclusive OR operation on each pair of corresponding bits. The
>   result in each position is 0 if both bits are 0, while otherwise the
>   result is 1.

So, `1|2: 001 | 010 = 011 (3 dec)`
and `2|3: 010 | 011 = 011 (3 dec)`

Comment: Ahh I see now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

0001 = 1 0010 = 2 so 0001 | 0010 = 0011 = 3.  0010 | 0011 = 0011 = 3.
| is the OR operation.

Answer (score 0):

> **x | y** Does a "bitwise or". Each bit of the output is 0 if the corresponding bit of x AND of y is 0, otherwise it's 1. 
>   https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

In your example, it is useful to look at the bit representation of an integer by the `bin()` function:

```
>>> bin(1), bin(2), bin(3)
('0b1', '0b10', '0b11')
```

So 1 is 01, 2 is 10 and 3 is 11. Therefore the bitwise OR operator applies to each pair of bits from right to left as: 1|2 is 01|10 = 11, 2|3 is 10|11 = 11
(0 or 1 gives 1, 1 or 1 gives 1)